# pickaday maxDate issue

Tags: javascript, datepicker, maxdate

I am creating a date picker by using `pickaday` but I'm getting stucked and confused with `maxDate` functionality. I set `maxDate` 7 years back but when I click on input to select date it shows me current month and year with all dates disabled, I want to show calender should show date which i set in `maxDate`. Please check my code below or you can check fiddle also https://jsfiddle.net/buffqvye/

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var picker = new Pikaday(
    {
        field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2009, 12, 31),
        yearRange: [2000,2009]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the **defaultDate** property.

```
var picker = new Pikaday(
{
   field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
   firstDay: 1,
   minDate: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
   maxDate: new Date(2009, 11, 31),
   yearRange: [2000,2009],
   defaultDate : new Date(2009, 11, 31)
});
```